# Update Query throwing Error in Command Line Bash only

Tags: bash, mariadb

I have the following query that I try to execute from a bash file:

```
echo 'update LOCKSTATUS'
if ! mysql -h site.com -u user -pPassword -D db -e "UPDATE tblcustomfieldsvalues a
JOIN
  (SELECT tblclients.userid,
          tblclients.company,
          tblcustomfieldsvalues.`value`,
          CoreUsers.`LOCKED_STATUS`,
          tblcustomfieldsvalues.id
   FROM tblclients
   LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues ON tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid = tblclients.userid
   AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldto = 'customers'
   AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = 16
   LEFT JOIN CoreUsers ON CoreUsers.USERID = tblclients.company) b
SET a.`value` = b.`LOCKED_STATUS`
WHERE a.id = b.id
  AND b.`LOCKED_STATUS` IS NOT NULL;"; then
  echo "Error: LOCK STATUS"
  exit 1
fi
```

this query works perfectly when executed through my mysql client. I wrapped some fields that could be problematic between `` but still, the bash file return an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
          CoreUsers.,
          tblcustomfieldsvalues.id
   FROM tblclients
...' at line 5
```

Comment: The error message indicates you are using MariaDB, not MySQL.

Comment: Backticks inside double quotes are a bad idea: the shell is going to treat them as command substitution syntax before they get to your database.

Answer (score 2):

When you use double-quoted strings in Bash, it enables command expansion, so back-ticks run a command and substitute the stdout of that command.

For example:

```
% echo "hello `date` world"
hello Wed Feb  1 15:15:13 PST 2023 world
```

In your case, you used back-ticks within a Bash double-quoted string, so it's going to try to run the command `value` and the command `LOCKED_STATUS`. Probably neither of these are valid commands on your system, so their stdout is empty.

Thus your SQL becomes:

```
...
SELECT tblclients.userid,
      tblclients.company,
      tblcustomfieldsvalues.,
      CoreUsers.,
      tblcustomfieldsvalues.id
...
```

This is a syntax error, because you have no column names after the `.` in those two lines.

You don't need to use back-ticks anyway around the column names. You would need to use back-ticks only if the columns conflict with [reserved keywords](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/), or if they contain punctuation or whitespace or something that makes them nonstandard identifiers. But `value` and `LOCKED_STATUS` are not reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75317199/14122) describes the problem and a solution that works in your immediate situation, but doesn't suggest how to fix it in the general case (which might include cases where you *really need* backticks). Here's a suggested fix that lets you keep your query as it's already written:

```bash
query=$(cat <<'__END_OF_QUERY'
UPDATE tblcustomfieldsvalues a
JOIN
  (SELECT tblclients.userid,
          tblclients.company,
          tblcustomfieldsvalues.`value`,
          CoreUsers.`LOCKED_STATUS`,
          tblcustomfieldsvalues.id
   FROM tblclients
   LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues ON tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid = tblclients.userid
   AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldto = 'customers'
   AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = 16
   LEFT JOIN CoreUsers ON CoreUsers.USERID = tblclients.company) b
SET a.`value` = b.`LOCKED_STATUS`
WHERE a.id = b.id
  AND b.`LOCKED_STATUS` IS NOT NULL;
__END_OF_QUERY
)

echo 'update LOCKSTATUS'
if ! mysql -h site.com -u user -pPassword -D db -e "$query"; then
  echo "Error: LOCK STATUS"
  exit 1
fi
```

This is because a quoted heredoc (as created by something like `<<'EOF'` or, in the above example, `<<'__END_OF_QUERY'` -- note the quotes, they're important) keeps everything until the next line containing only and exactly the sigil (`__END_OF_QUERY` in this case) *completely* unmodified.